# problem with regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need regexp for expression: "`dsfsdf|dfdfdf|Gfgfgfg|ghghfgh|fgfjghjg`"
Between "|" may be any sequences of symbols.

I have tried this expression: `[a-z]+\|[a-z]+` but it contains similar code ([a-z]+). I want expression without copy-paste because in fact my expression is more complex.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? To split the string or just test it against the pattern?

Comment: just test it against the pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
(?:[A-Za-z]+\|?)+
```

The `(?:)` is a non capturing group and the `\|?` is looking for one or 0 |

You can add any character you are looking for between the `[]`. There are also predefined character sets like `\w` for word characters (I am not sure what is defined as a word character within c# .net at least A-Za-z and _ )

Comment: Your solution finds expression like this: "qweqe|qw|eqwerer|" too, but i need "|" only in middle.

Comment: Then I am sure there is a solution using a lookahead assertion (I am sorry, not getting it to work at the moment), but this is also a complex expression. I think your expression `[a-z]+\|[a-z]+` is then easier to read. And I would not name it copy-paste what you are doing here, you are describing your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the next expression:

```
^[^|].*[^|]$
```

it matches a string if it isn't begins or ends with the `|` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `string.Split('|')`?

If you want to verify that your string is valid use `[a-z|]+`